# Problem running emscripten c++ web application on android device for testing

Tags: android, c++, adb, emscripten

I'm trying to run my web based c++ application on my android phone so i can do mobile testing with the application I'm working on. I've connected my android phone through usb, and i'm able to run basic command from the pc to tell the phone to open the google chrome app, so should all be connected fine. My problem is when I run the command

```
emrun --android --browser firefox index.html
```

in cmd, i get the error

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=http://192.168.1.98:6931/... cmp=org.mozilla.firefox/.App }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {org.mozilla.firefox/org.mozilla.firefox.App} does not exist.
```

I can run the same code without the android tag on the computer's browser just fine, it's when trying to get it to run on the mobile device i have the issue.

Based of the emscripten documentation ([here](https://emscripten.org/docs/compiling/Running-html-files-with-emrun.html#running-web-pages-on-an-android-device)) I think i'm using the correct command. I've also tried resetting both the computer and phone. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I've found a bit of a work around for this is anyone is wondering. It turns out that when you use

> emrun your_file.index

it creates a local webpage that can be accessed by any device on the network. The webpage can be accessed using:

```
http://ComputerIP:EmscriptenPort/
```

You can replace ComputerIP with the ip address of the computer that's hosting it, and EmscriptenPort with the port emscripten is using(defualt 6931). If you enter this webpage from your mobile you can view your emscripten project. Just requires refreshing the website every time you re-build your project.

If you want to automate it a bit more I'm sure you could write a .bat file that will run a few commands through adb to refresh the mobiles' webpage every time you make a new build. If I do that at some point I will add it here.

Not quite the solution to the question but it achieves what's needed.